# Slow build with android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I can't comment on any answer because my reputation isn't 50 so i have ask a question here.
I have just started learning android development with java android studio and when ever i compile even few line of code the android studio take forever to build and execute. My android emulator is already running. So I looked on the internet for an answer and find the following link 
stackoverflow.com/questions/25006075/extremely-long-build-with-gradle-android-studio

But as I am a total beginner I have no clue where I have to put the following code if some one can elaborate it a little or provide a snap shot or a blog tutorial for it i ll be great full. I am talking about the following code at the end of it and I am not bad at programming but its my first go on the android studio so hope you can understand How can a noob like me understand how to deal with this situation. Any help from you folk will highly be appreciated. If you think that this is a copy of another question don't worry just let me know and I ll delete the question once I have my answer
Regards,

My problem,
1) I don't know what is module's build file.
2) what does it mean exactly by adding it to android block. 
3) what is this dxOptions? and why their not a quick enable or disable option provided by the android studio itself.

This is answer that I can't understand regarding my problem/situation.

Answer : I'm not quite sure why Android Studio is slower than the command line, but you can speed up your builds by turning on incremental dexing. In your module's build file, add this option to your android block:

dexOptions {
    incremental true
}
In that dexOptions block you can also specify the heap size for the dex process, for example:

dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
These options are taken from a thread on the adt-dev mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/r4p-sBLl7DQ) which has a little more context.

My system is i3 2.6 ghz 4gb ram

I am talking about simple hello world application
gradle build finish is 4 to 5 min.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize with solutions follow:

1. Open the file [Installation Folder]\studio64.exe.vmoptions or studio.exe.vmoptions, depending on which version you're using. And modify value of params:

   -Xms128m

   -Xmx750m

You can boost the firt value to 256 and the second value to 1024 or higher if you like.

2. Speeding up Gradle build time

   - First, go to Settings/Compiler and check everything, **except** for the 2nd option Make project automatically
   - For VM Options, we use these configurations

   -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

   - Next, add the following lines to gradle.properties in your project directory

   org.gradle.daemon=true
   org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
   org.gradle.parallel=true
   org.gradle.configureondemand=true